# Problems converting JSON objects in Scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing, json4s

I'm trying to make a simple example of a class **serialization** in Scala using **json4s** library, but even after extensively searching for it on the internet, unfortunately I couldn't find any satisfatory sample that would solve my problem.

Basically I have a simple class called `Person` and I want to extract an instance of this class from a JSON string.

```
case class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val children: Option[List[Person]]
)
```

So when I do this:

```
val jsonStr = "{\"name\":\"Socrates\", \"age\": 70}"
println(Serialization.read[Person](jsonStr))
```

I get this output:

```
"Person(Socrates,70,None)" // works fine!
```

But when I have no *age* parameter in JSON string, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for age

I know that `Person` class has two required parameters in its constructor, but I would like to know if there's a way to make this conversion through a parser or something similar.

Also, I've tried to make this parser, but no success.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you want to receive as a result of parsing the JSON when there is no "age" parameter?

Comment: Obviously you need to use Option[Int] type for age or create your custom serializer: https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-non-supported-types

Comment: @dan-getz, I will receive those JSON strings from a third party application, so I cannot guarantee that all parameters will be present on their requests, so I'm just trying to figure it out the options I have to make my parser robust (I started studying Scala language just a week ago).

Comment: @sap1ens, as I said, I've tried to make this parser using this exact sample, but no success. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "What are my options?" You could leave the existing exception as is, throw a different exception, return an `Option`, return a special value, use `Option` for the `age` parameter, use a special `age` number to represent "not specified", return a `Try` or `Either`... the list goes on and on. Are you asking for help coding a parser, or deciding what your code should do in the first place?

Comment: My question is about both, deciding what my code should do and how to make this parser. I don't see anything wrong with that once I'm not an expert in this language.

Comment: Ok, but we're not experts in what you need to use this code for, which is why I was asking. Without knowing that, my first instinct is that your code above works perfectly well. For some reason, you don't think so. Isn't that because of what you need to use the code for?

Comment: I have many elements that will be serialized at the same time, so an exception could ruin my logic. I want to be able to check if that object is okay without generating exceptions, but only returning true or false in a method like `isValid`. It would be satisfatory for the architecture I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to make age optional by setting its type to `Option`, then you could write a custom serializer by extending `CustomSerializer[Person]`. The custom serializer takes a function from `Formats` to a tuple of `PartialFunction[JValue, Person]` (your `Person` deserializer) and `PartialFunction[Any, JValue]` (your serializer).

Assuming `Person.DefaultAge` is the default value you want to set for age if the age is not given, then the custom serializer could look as follows:

```
object PersonSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Person](formats => ( {
  case JObject(JField("name", JString(name)) :: JField("age", JInt(age)) :: Nil) => Person(name, age.toInt, None)
  case JObject(JField("name", JString(name)) :: JField("age", JInt(age)) :: JField("children", JArray(children)) :: Nil) => Person(name, age.toInt, Some(children map (child => formats.customDeserializer(formats).apply(TypeInfo(classOf[Person], None), child).asInstanceOf[Person])))
  case JObject(JField("name", JString(name)) :: Nil) => Person(name, Person.DefaultAge, None)
  case JObject(JField("name", JString(name)) :: JField("children", JArray(children)) :: Nil) => Person(name, Person.DefaultAge, Some(children map (child => formats.customDeserializer(formats).apply(TypeInfo(classOf[Person], None), child).asInstanceOf[Person])))
}, {
  case Person(name, age, None) => JObject(JField("name", JString(name)) :: JField("age", JInt(age)) :: Nil)
  case Person(name, age, Some(children)) => JObject(JField("name", JString(name)) :: JField("age", JInt(age)) :: JField("children", formats.customSerializer(formats).apply(children)) :: Nil)
}))
```

This could probably be simplified as there is a lot of repetition. Also, there might be a better way to recursively call serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Thank you very much, @KuluLimpa! It worked softly as I expected.